# Command Line Interface & Process Control

Tags: c, command-line-interface

Given a process which accept command line input as below

```
 $ ./app
 > init
 initialized.
 > start
 started.
 > stop
 stopped.
```

Is it possible to write a shell script or another C program which trigger ./app, and inject command sequentially? Let say the script-to-be-written will inject string "init", and wait for reply string "initialized.", then inject "start", and wait for reply "started.", and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Unix `expect` tool has been created for exactly this scenario. You provide a script where you state the expected string (like `initialized`) and declare the appropriate action following that string. Of course there is also some kind of "START" thing.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect for examples.

Comment: Arh!!! Thanks for reminding me about "expect"! I remember having a method to do so, but can't remember how it has been done.